# On AppSync, how to query a model sort by many to many relation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

I have this schema :

```
type Brand @model
  @key(name: "ByName", fields: ["name"])
  @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  link: String
  image: String
  bio: String
  votes: [Vote] @connection(keyName: "byBrand", fields: ["id"])
}


type Vote @model
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID"]) ## BelongsTo User. Index by userId
  @key(name: "byBrand", fields: ["brandID", "userID"], queryField: "voteByBrand")
  @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  userID: String!
  userPhone: String!
  brandID: ID!
  # productTypeID: ID!
  image: String
  comment: String
  # BelongTo User
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  # BelongTo Brand
  brand: Brand! @connection(fields: ["brandID"])
}
```

I want to query all Brand and sort by Brand which have the most votes.

Brand 1 -> 20 votes ; Brand 2 -> 15 votes ; Brand 3 -> 8 votes ; Brand 4 -> 5 votes ;

On appSync, it seems not possible. Can you help me for that?